# geometry nodes. perdendicular angle to line

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a line guided by 2 empties. Then I have another line that starts in both empties an is perpendicular to the first line using cross product. What I need is a parameter in the input group to control the angle of those two lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you meant the following example:

[image]

Here, the vector (endpoint) of your new line is simply rotated around a certain axis using the node `Vector Rotate`.

[image]

And here is the blend file:

[image]